# cubesviewer work with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, json, python-2.7, cubes

Does cubesviewer that Jose Juan Montes created work with internet explorer 9.0?

I even tried to load http://jjmontesl.github.io/cubesviewer/index.html and it indicated that it cannot create cubesViewer.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

It should work, although I cannot test on that browser. If it doesn't you shall file a issue to the project Issue tracker: https://github.com/jjmontesl/cubesviewer/issues for further investigation.